# Laravel: Permission denied in laravel Blade File

Tags: php, installation, permission-denied, laravel

I have the following issue when trying to install Laravel http://laravel.com

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

> Unhandled Exception
>
> Message:
>
> file_put_contents(/Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/storage/views/26bdebca7505781c753aa21663170a1b)
>   [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
>     Location:
>
> /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/blade.php on line 63    Stack
>   Trace:
>
> #0 /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/laravel.php(40):
>   Laravel\Error::native(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/Users/alvincre...',
>   63)   #1 [internal function]: Laravel{closure}(2,
>   'file_put_conten...', '/Users/alvincre...', 63, Array)    #2
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/blade.php(63):
>   file_put_contents('/Users/alvincre...', '...')    #3 [internal
>   function]: Laravel{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))    #4
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/event.php(199):
>   call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)  #5
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/event.php(138):
>   Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)    #6
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/view.php(325):
>   Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)     #7
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/view.php(546):
>   Laravel\View->render()    #8
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/response.php(246):
>   Laravel\View->__toString()    #9
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/laravel/laravel.php(138):
>   Laravel\Response->render()    #10
>   /Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/public/index.php(34):
>   require('/Users/alvincre...')     #11 {main}

Comment: Not sure if it was the permissions on my comp but I basically did a chmod -R 777 apollo/ and it worked. I know this is probably not the best solution.

Comment: Can you try changing to 775 and see if it still works?

Comment: Second the above, 777 is v dangerous.

Comment: Had same issue, 775 works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would check that the permissions on:

```
/Users/alvincrespo/Sites/apollo/storage/views/26bdebca7505781c753aa21663170a1b
```

Allow your application to write to this directory.

Assuming you are on a linux box you could run ls -l to see what the permissions are, and if it is set to read only, change the permissions with chmod.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the very good documentation under install, you have to make the directory storage/views writeable.

http://laravel.com/docs/install#installation

Answer (score 2):

Although it’s an old question but I hope this might help someone, here is what solved the problem for me.

```sh
sudo chmod -R 754 storage/
```

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of /storage directory in the laravel installation. The views directory must have write permisison for the webserver that is it.